# How to know the value of input password field?

Tags: javascript, html

Given a page with the following element:

```
<input name="my_field" type="password">
```

Obviously, I see only the dots in the browser. Is there a way to fetch the value from the developer console?

Comment: did you tried `document.getElementsByName('my_field')[0].value`?

Comment: @Mritunjay not till now - it works! would you like to put it as an answer? thanks anyways!

Comment: @Mritunjay why the downvote if so? (I'll be able to mark your answer in 10 mins)

Comment: I didn't give a downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you

```
document.getElementsByName('my_field')[0].value
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
document.getElementsByName('my_field')[0].value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
document.getElementsByName("my_field")[0].type = "text"
```

Which will make the password field cleartext.

But the shortest way is to this is: Right click to the password field, click Inspect Element, find the `type="password"` and make it `type="text"`

Last one requires minimum time and typing, but the rest works too